# How to change month calendar by a button instead of direct interaction?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a GUI desktop application, where one can enter a date into a text box and pushing a button returns another date. I also use a month calender alternative to choose the date, and when one selects a date from the month calendar, the text box changes automatically. So far so good.

But here is my problem. As I explained, the text box input changes when one selects a date from the month calendar. But I couldn't figure out the other way around. I want the month calendar to automatically change when some one enters a date to the text box and pushes the button. Otherwise text box and month calendar show different dates, and it is not okay for the purpose of application.

Is there a way to modify the month calendar by a text input followed by a push button instead of using the mouse?

Here is my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
          //...
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          string choosefridaydate = textBox1.Text;

          //code
        }

        private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = monthCalendar1.SelectionRange.Start.Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            button1.PerformClick();
        }
    }         
}
```

Comment: Have a change event for the field and call `.setDat (Date)`?

Comment: i didnt understand your question? but what ever i tried it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `SelectionStart` and `SelectionEnd` property to the date obtained converting the string typed in the textbox

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dt;
    string choosefridaydate = textBox1.Text;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(choosefridaydate, out dt))
    {
        monthCalendar1.SelectionStart = dt;
        monthCalendar1.SelectionEnd = dt;
    }
}
```

This approach uses the DateTime.TryParse to convert the string typed by your user in a date. If the format cannot be recognized as a valid date according to the international settings of the user PC the TryParse will return false and the MonthCalendar will not be set.

In this case you need to use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) specifyng which format your user is allowed to type in the textbox

There is also the SetDate method that could change the current selected date, but again you need first to convert your input textbox to a valid date

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime dt;
    string choosefridaydate = textBox1.Text;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(choosefridaydate, out dt))
    {
        monthCalendar1.SetDate(dt);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
According to your comment, if the date is in the format `yyyyMMdd` then you need to use DateTime.TryParseExact

```
DateTime dt;
string choosefridaydate = textBox1.Text;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(choosefridaydate, "yyyyMMdd", 
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
    monthCalendar1.SetDate(dt);
```

Comment: it didnt work, calendar stays the same, no change occurs.. btw choosefridaydate is in yyyyMMdd format. can it be a reason?

Comment: Yes, probably TryParse returns false. I will update the answer using DateTime.TryParseExact

Comment: this worked:                 if (DateTime.TryParseExact(choosefridaydate,"yyyyMMdd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,out dt))